# Checkbox keeps being checked, even if jQuery says it should not

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, authentication, checkbox, cordova

I'm just working on a simple Login-Screen for a Phonegap Application (jQuery Mobile).

Everything works fine and the user is even possible to save the login data by clicking a checkbox (I use localStorage.) Now I want to redirect the user to the login screen with an unchecked checkbox, when the user clicks on a Logout-Button. Redirecting works fine and the password is deleted. The only problem is the checkbox, which keeps being checked, even though I am telling it to be unchecked.

Here is my code:

html

```
...
<form id="login">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="usr" /><br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
    <label for="checkbox-1">Stay logged in</label>

    <a data-role="button" data-transition="none" id="logindata" onclick="LogIn()">Login</a>

</form>
...
```

javascript

```
//checking if there is already a saved password. if yes, setting values
function checkStorage() {

    if ( localStorage["pw"] != null){

        document.getElementById("usr").value = localStorage["name"];
        document.getElementById("pwd").value = localStorage["pw"];
        $("#checkbox-1").prop("checked", true);

    } 

}

function LogIn() {

    var usr = document.getElementById('usr').value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value; 

    //always saving the name
    localStorage["name"] = usr;

    //if checkbox checked, save the password. if not, delete saved password
    if ( $("#checkbox-1").is(":checked") ) {

        localStorage["pw"] = pwd;

    } else {

        if (localStorage["pw"] != null){

            localStorage.removeItem("pw");

        }

    }

    $.ajax({

        url: 'https://myurl',
        async: false,
        username: usr,
        password: pwd,
        success: function () {
            $.mobile.changePage("#success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Please enter correct username and password!");
        }

    });
}

function LogOut() {

    var usr = "";
    var pwd = "";

    $.mobile.changePage("#index");
    document.getElementById("usr").value = localStorage["name"];
    document.getElementById("pwd").value = "";
    localStorage.removeItem("pw");

    //This code is not working?
    $("#checkbox-1").prop("checked", false);

}
```

When I get this code working, I want to encode the password, but for now I just want to get it working. ;)

I hope, there is anyone, who could help me?

**EDIT:**

I finally found out, what's going on. I'm using jQuery Mobile for this login form and there checkboxes have to be refreshed! So the following code works for me now:

```
$("#checkbox-1").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a

```
removeProp("checked")
```

rather than

```
prop("checked", false)
```

I think you should have more success.

**EDIT**

Just a thought, is your login form inside the element with the id index? If so will the changepage not need to be below the localstorage.removeitem?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but unfortunately it's still not working. The checkbox keeps being checked, if it was checked at the login. When it was not checked, it's not checked at the logout, too. :(

Comment: You are right. The Login-Form is inside of the element with the id index. I put changepage below the localStorage.removeItem, so this should definitely work now. But the checkbox issue still remains... :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#checkbox-1").is(':checked')){
         $('#checkbox-1').removeAttr('checked'); 
        }



})
```

[demo test](http://jsfiddle.net/RbSbA/1/)